# Is it possible to detect there is a motion happening from only an image(no referening is given)

Tags: image, image-processing

I have searched around the internet, only seen motion detection can be done in video or two  consecutive images. I wonder is that possible to detect a motion from an image(like jumping running swimming).The motion is referring any significant body movement. If it can be done, please tell me the algorithm and ways to learn it. thank you

Comment: How would you detect motion with only a single frame?  The question itself doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think a static motion involve a person is sitting or standing. So we need to detect both hand and leg to check whether these are horizontal or perpendicular to the ground.It doesn't make sense only because it is not implemented well in this moment. I do hope that it can be done someday

Comment: You'll never be able to differentiate actual walking from someone holding a walk-like pose.

Comment: I know using one frame is a hard mission and there are so many limit. It is sad but true.Maybe a walk-like pose can be count as a dynamic motion, since it is better than just standing on the ground.

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, for the general case, you probably can't.  But, there are still avenues to explore, if you have control over some of the parameters.
One idea that comes to mind is detecting motion blur for some fast movement.  You can accent that if you have control over the camera type/exposure.

You can find academic papers on the subject, and can start with:
https://www.google.com/search?q=detecting+motion+blur+in+one+image

Answer (score 0):

A technique that can be helpful to you is called **scene understanding**. Basically you train a deep neural net with images and labels that describe that image. In that way you can know that a person is running, swimming or doing any other activity.

There is a good [presentation about the subject](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~yann/talks/lecun-20130623-cvpr-sunw.pdf) by Prof. LeCun.

Answer (score 0):

What yu are implying is an implicit comparison with an image of a person standng in a "stable/not moving directed way. So there is a two image comparison there non-withstanding.